# How to shift my shared folder from /mnt to Desktop in ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, automount

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.04 in my MAC using virtual box. I mounted two of my folders in MAC using virtual box. But the problem is, I created my shared folder called "share" inside /mnt.

How do I get the Share folder to appear on the desktop and how do I get it to auto-mount on start-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

auto mount on startup should be a virtualbox setting when you set up the share , you will need guest additions installed to use the share i believe.

you could simply link the directory from /mnt to your desktop

this would be done in the terminal by typing

```
ln -s /mnt/share ~/Desktop
```

you may need to try sudo !! if it's denied.
or I'm sure there's an option to show network servers on desktop , most likely in your desktop settings , I don't remember 10.04 well

Comment: i managed to link the directory to my desktop, but can't get it to mount automatically on start-up. While creating the shared folders in virtual box, i checked the "mount automatically" check-box(not sure if this is what you said i had to do) . I got to know that i have to add a line in the fstab file located in /etc to auto mount on start-up. This is the command i used to mount my folder             "mount -t vboxsf Assignments share " where share is the folder that i created in the /mnt folder. Could anyone tell me what line am i supposed to include in the fstab file?

Comment: i think this may need to be posted as a new question.

but yes thats exactly right i meant auto-mount in vbox's options ,i'm not sure what you need to add fstab though